# How can I convert or get the exact value from ctypes.c_byte

Tags: python, ctypes

So, I am using ctypes to call a dll function. I pass in the return variable by_ref(). In code it looks like:

```
mydll = cdll('dllpath')

terminal_id = BYTE()
print("terminal id before api call:",terminal_id)
ret = mydll.func(input,byref(terminal_id))
print("terminal id after api call:",terminal_id)
```

The following code prints:

`terminal id before api call:c_byte(0)
 terminal id after api call:c_byte(53)`

I have a gui to interact with the terminal from the gui the terminal id is :6380491601819081

How can I extract this from the returned terminal_id variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6380491601819081 can't fit in a byte. The type isn't large enough.

Comment: I was using the wrong datatype for the return value. It worked when I took the output with c_buffer().

Comment: I would have been more detailed but I had no way to find the declaration of the function you were calling.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using `terminal_id.value`.

`print(dir(terminal_id))` will show the attributes and methods of the `c_byte` type.

A `c_byte` in ctypes seems to be a `char` in C ([ctypes doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)).

```
import ctypes
x = ctypes.c_byte(3)
print(dir(x))
print(x.value)
```

Comment: `terminal_id.value` outputs 53. Does that mean the terminal id is 53 ? So what does `c_byte(0).value ; 0` mean?

Comment: A `c_byte` is a number between 0 and 255. And it's just that. Binary 0 is `00000000`. Binary 53 is `00110101`